# Cannot change color of StatusBar in React Native Android

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to change the background color of the status bar in my React Native Android app, but the API does not work in my case. Other props like `hidden`, `barStyle`, `animated` and `translucent` work fine but changing `backgroundColor` has no effect.

My code:

```
return (
    <>
        <StatusBar
            backgroundColor="#772ea2"
            barStyle="light-content"
            animated
            translucent={true}
        />
...
```

I am using React Native 0.63.3 and physical Android devices running Android 11 and 8.

Are there any other considerations I have to make in the code to make this work? How can it be fixed?

Comment: It should work. Can you check where you placed it?

Comment: @HaseebA Thanks yes I have updated the code snippet

Answer (score 2):

The reason that it this prop didn't work was that I had this code in an Android style:

```xml
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item> -->
  </style>
```