# StatusBar react native android 11 don't work

Tags: android, react-native, statusbar, android-11

I follow the next example but doesn´t work.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar#setbackgroundcolor-android

I use React native and CLI

I wanna change background, only work parameters hidden and translucent.

I try [Cannot change color of StatusBar in React Native Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64316423/cannot-change-color-of-statusbar-in-react-native-android) but doesn´t work.

Comment: Can you show me for your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.